# Retrieving data from blank nodes in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am attempting to retrieve data about the lifespans of certain people. This is problematic in cases of people that have lived a while ago. The dataset for e.g. [Pythagoras](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10261) seems to have a so called "blank node" for `date of birth (P569)`. But this blank node references another node `earliest date (P1319)` which has data I could work with just fine.

But for some reason I am not able to retrieve that node. [My first try looked like this](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3Fname%20%3Fdateofbirth%20%3Fearliestdateofbirth%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%20%23%20Is%20Human%0A%20%3Fperson%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname.%20%23%20Name%20for%20better%20conformation%0A%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fdateofbirth.%20%23%20May%20result%20in%20a%20blank%20node%0A%20%3Fdateofbirth%20wdt%3AP1319%20%3Fearliestdateofbirth%0A%7D), but somehow that results in a completly empty result set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?name ?dateofbirth ?earliestdateofbirth WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.         # This thing is Human
  ?person rdfs:label ?name.      # Name for better conformation
  ?person wdt:P569 ?dateofbirth. # Birthday may result in a blank node
  ?dateofbirth wdt:P1319 ?earliestdateofbirth # Problem: Plausbible Birth
}
```

I then found another Syntax that suggested using `?person wdt:P569/wdt:P1319 ?earliestdateofbirth` as some kind of "shortcut"-syntax for the explicit navigation I did above [but this also ends with a empty result set](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3Fname%20%3Fdateofbirth%20%3Fearliestdateofbirth%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%20%23%20Is%20Human%0A%20%3Fperson%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname.%20%23%20Name%20for%20better%20conformation%0A%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP569%2Fwdt%3AP1319%20%3Fearliestdateofbirth.%20%0A%7D).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?name ?dateofbirth ?earliestdateofbirth WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.         # Is Human
  ?person rdfs:label ?name.      # Name for better conformation
  ?person wdt:P569/wdt:P1319 ?earliestdateofbirth. 
}
```

So how do I access a node referenced by a blank node (in my case specifically the earliest birthdate) in Wikidata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But this blank node references another node…

Things are slightly different. The `earliest date` property is not a property of `_:t550690019`, but rather is a property of the *statement* `wd:Q10261 wdt:P569 _:t550690019`.

In the Wikidata [data model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format), these annotations are expressed using [qualifiers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format).

[image: Wikidata data model]

Your query should be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?name ?dateofbirth ?earliestdateofbirth WHERE {
  VALUES (?person) {(wd:Q10261)}
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.         # --Is human
  ?person rdfs:label ?name.      # --Name for better conformation
  ?person p:P569/pq:P1319 ?earliestdateofbirth. 
  FILTER (lang(?name) = "en")
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3Fname%20%3Fdateofbirth%20%3Fearliestdateofbirth%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fperson%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ10261%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Is%20Human%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname.%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Name%20for%20better%20conformation%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20p%3AP569%2Fpq%3AP1319%20%3Fearliestdateofbirth.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fname%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%7D)

---

By the way, *time precision* (which is used when date of birth is known) is yet another qualifier:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?value ?precisionLabel {
  VALUES (?person) {(wd:Q859) (wd:Q9235)}
  ?person  wdt:P31  wd:Q5 ;
           p:P569/psv:P569  [ wikibase:timeValue  ?value ;
                              wikibase:timePrecision  ?precisionInteger ]
  {
  SELECT ?precision (xsd:integer(?precisionDecimal) AS ?precisionInteger) {
    ?precision  wdt:P2803  ?precisionDecimal .
  }
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fvalue%20%3FprecisionLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fperson%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ859%29%20%28wd%3AQ9235%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20%20wdt%3AP31%20%20wd%3AQ5%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%3AP569%2Fpsv%3AP569%20%20%5B%20wikibase%3AtimeValue%20%20%3Fvalue%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AtimePrecision%20%20%3FprecisionInteger%20%5D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20SELECT%20%3Fprecision%20%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3FprecisionDecimal%29%20AS%20%3FprecisionInteger%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprecision%20wdt%3AP2803%20%3FprecisionDecimal%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D.%0A%7D)

Comment: I feel stupid, but I can't spot it right away: It does work, but what does your query do different? The `FILTER` and `VALUES` seems to only restrict it more.

Comment: Look carefully :). I'll explain in a few minutes, now I'm looking for good links.

Comment: Ah, you are using different prefixes for `P569` and `P1319`, I would be glad to have some good links for that!

Comment: Wow, thanks for updating your answer so thoroughly, this really helps!