# Wikidata:SPARQL Query Service Units

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

How do I get unit type and date precision in the Wikidata Query service (https://query.wikidata.org) with SPARQL?

Below is example query looking at dimensions and inception of tapestries.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?height ?width ?inception
WHERE
{
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q184296 .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?item wdt:P2048 ?height .
        ?item wdt:P2049 ?width .
        ?item wdt:P571 ?inception .
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
} LIMIT 1
```

I see on website that Bayeux Tapestry (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q187483) is measured in metres and was made in 1070s. But when I use Query Service, I get numbers only for height and width. And Inception is 1070s on website, but Jan 1, 1070 on Query Service. I looked at documentation but can't figure out.

How can I get units and date precision on Query Service?

Answer (score 3):

Getting information about statements and units works this way in Wikidata:

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
       ?height ?unitHeightLabel 
       ?width ?unitWidthLabel 
       ?inception ?precisionLabel WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q184296 . 
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item p:P2048 ?stmnodeHeight . # height
    ?stmnodeHeight       psv:P2048                   ?valuenodeHeight.
    ?valuenodeHeight     wikibase:quantityAmount     ?height.
    ?valuenodeHeight     wikibase:quantityUnit       ?unitHeight.

    ?item p:P2049 ?stmnodeWidth . # width
    ?stmnodeWidth       psv:P2049                   ?valuenodeWidth.
    ?valuenodeWidth     wikibase:quantityAmount     ?width.
    ?valuenodeWidth     wikibase:quantityUnit       ?unitWidth.

    ?item p:P571/psv:P571 ?timenode .
    ?timenode wikibase:timeValue         ?inception.
    ?timenode wikibase:timePrecision     ?timeprecision.
    # get the label of time precision (by @StanislavKralin)
    {
     SELECT ?precision (xsd:integer(?precisionDecimal) AS ?timeprecision) {
     ?precision  wdt:P2803  ?precisionDecimal .
     }
    }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" } 
} LIMIT 1
```

A slightly more compact version using SPARQL 1.1 property paths + Turtle shortcuts:

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
       ?height ?unitHeightLabel 
       ?width ?unitWidthLabel 
       ?inception ?precisionLabel WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q184296 . 
  OPTIONAL {
    # height
    ?item p:P2048/psv:P2048 [ wikibase:quantityAmount     ?height ;
                              wikibase:quantityUnit       ?unitHeight ].

    # width
    ?item p:P2049/psv:P2049 [ wikibase:quantityAmount     ?width ;
                              wikibase:quantityUnit       ?unitWidth ].
    # inception
    ?item p:P571/psv:P571 [ wikibase:timeValue         ?inception;
                            wikibase:timePrecision     ?timeprecision ]
    # get the label of time precision (by @StanislavKralin)
    {
     SELECT ?precision (xsd:integer(?precisionDecimal) AS ?timeprecision) {
     ?precision  wdt:P2803  ?precisionDecimal .
     }
    }

  } 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" } 
} LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------+----------------+-------------+---------------+
|    item     |    itemLabel    | height | unitHeightLabel | width | unitWidthLabel |  inception  | precisionLabel |
+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------+----------------+-------------+---------------+
|  wd:Q187483 | Bayeux Tapestry |    0.5 | metre           | 68.38 | metre          | Jan 1, 1070 |             8 |
+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------+----------------+-------------+---------------+
```

> The codes for precision are 0: billion years, 1: hundred million years, 3: million years, 4: hundred thousand years, 5: ten thousand years, 6: millennium, 7: century, 8: decade, 9: year, 10: month, 11: day, 12: hour, 13: minute, 14: second.

Comment: AKSW, excellent answer! Minor comment: one could retrive textual representations of these precision codes using `P2803`: see e.g [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197121/7879193) (but unfortunately type conversion looks unavoidable).

Comment: Oh sure, I didn't know that. Thanks!